# After server restart, network.service is either failed or inactive CENTOS 7

Tags: linux-networking, centos7

This seems to happen alot (on this site), and I have tried the other remedies, to no avail. I will list the problem, then what I have tried.

I restarted the server a couple days ago, when it restarted SLURM didn't work and neither did the network.service. `systemctl reset-failed` fixed the `slurmd error`, but only changes the network.service from `failed` to `inactive`, both of which are not useful.

Here is what I have when I do `systemctl status network.service` after rebooting the server just now:

```
$ systemctl status network
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-02-11 11:18:25 PST; 1min 37s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2234 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 2.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/network.service
           └─2582 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-5d899a3b-67e6-4888-9c5b-06f30b255ff5-enp2s0f1.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-enp2s0f1.pid -H c110370 enp2s0f1
```

After trying `systemctl reset-failed` it becomes:

```
 (base) [dummy_name]$ sudo systemctl reset-failed
(base) [dummy_name]$ systemctl status network
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-02-11 11:18:25 PST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2234 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 2.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/network.service
           └─2582 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-5d899a3b-67e6-4888-9c5b-06f30b255ff5-enp2s0f1.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-enp2s0f1.pid -H c110370 enp2s0f1
```

I have tried stopping and disabling `NetworkManager`, to no avail. What am I missing (I am not in IT)

The error message `2234 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)` is probably key, but googling it just brings up the usual network.service suspects saying to `reset-failed` or disable `NetworkManager`.

---

As per comment request

```
    (base) [dumm_name ~]$ ifconfig
enp2s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:5d:64:be:32:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfd620000-fd63ffff

enp2s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.10.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.100.10.255
        inet6 fe80::d65d:64ff:febe:32c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d4:5d:64:be:32:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70355  bytes 6270680 (5.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2412  bytes 176319 (172.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfd600000-fd61ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 52637  bytes 2650010 (2.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52637  bytes 2650010 (2.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Can you please show your nic configuration?

Comment: Hello @ItaiGanot, I have added the output from `ipconfig`. If that isn't what you wanted, please let me know.